# Classicthesis conflicts with glossaries

Tags: glossaries, classicthesis

The following command in `classicthesis` gives an error when using `glossaries`

```
\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace*{\labelsep}\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}
```

giving the following result in the document for both acronyms and glossaries.

> LO@SAMPLE@NAME a sample entry. 1

Is there a workaround since I like the small caps in glossaries?

Here is the minimal NWE

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample}, description={a sample entry}}
\begin{document}
A \gls{sample} entry.
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

The \renewcommand in conflict is on line 389 in `classicthesis.sty`

Comment: The documentation of `classicthesis` says on pages 7–8 to use the `glossaries` package like this: `\usepackage[style=long,nolist]{glossaries}`

Comment: @Crissov And doing `\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}` will print the entry name in spaced small caps.

Comment: @Crissov thanks, I know for long that «When everything else failed, read the manual!», but still forget to do it :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combining the infos from the documentation and @egreg this should be a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage[style=long,nolist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample}, description={a sample entry}}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}
\begin{document}
A \gls{sample} entry.
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```