# Can't compile glossary

Tags: glossaries

Sorry for the newbie question, but I can't figure out where to check.

I'm writing a thesis and this is my main document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,numbers=enddot,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % Lasciare così, serve a codificare i caratteri accentati
\usepackage[top=3.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[eulermath,dottedtoc,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{hyperref} % Creare collegamenti email e siti web
\hypersetup{hidelinks} % Nasconde i riquadri attorno ai link ed ai riferimenti incrociati
\usepackage[english]{varioref} % Serve a scrivere la pagina di riferimento del rif. incrociato
\usepackage[french,UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[center,font=small]{caption}[2004/07/16]
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xcolor} % Per creare testo colorato
\usepackage{multirow} % Per le multirighe nelle tabelle
\usepackage{glossaries} % Pacchetto per il glossario
\makeglossary
\loadglsentries{gloss} % Percorso del glossario
\setacronymstyle{short-long} % Stile per caricare le parole dal glossario
\usepackage{empheq}

\graphicspath{{Pictures/}}

\author{John Doe}
\title{Asfinterli}
\date{}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

The glossary file I'm loading (gloss.tex) is the following:

```
\newacronym{EMS}{EMS}{Energy Management System}
\newacronym{HS}{HS}{Hybrid System}
\newacronym{PMS}{PMS}{Power Management System}
\newacronym{PEMFC}{PEMFC}{Polymer Electrolyte Membrane Fuel Cell}
\newacronym{SOFC}{SOFC}{Solid-Oxyde Fuel Cell}
\newacronym[description={A power plant using an heat engine to generate electricity and useful heat simultaneously}]%
    {CHP}{CHP}{Combined Heat and Power}
```

I'm using TeXstudio 2.10.8 on Windows 8.1. Whenever I try to build the file, TeXstudio loops and it doesn't finish it, so I don't know where are the errors.

I think it could be a problem in the order of loading the packages.

P.S. I accept also suggestions whether you find other errors :P

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We can't compile this since it consists of a lot of files we don't have access to. Can you please clearify, what doesn't work here? Does the compilation break?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't include everything, I'll try to upload a new version that could work.

The compilation doesn't break, anyway.

Comment: Yes, please reduce it to the absolute minimum that still shows the issue

Comment: Hope it works now
P.S. I left all the packages because I would like to know if the order is fine or not

Comment: `\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}`. And the `caption` package has been updated ;-) A 2004 version is not really feasible

Comment: `classicthesis` is the culprit!!! (As usual. Please don't use that package -- it causes more problems than it's useful for some particular purpose)

Comment: OT: I thought that _caption_ package was the last one, maybe the guide was too old.

Wait, I also have _\newglossaryentry_ voices (I just haven't written them in the gloss.tex file): does it change anything?

Comment: In this case, remove `nomain` then (or don't add it ;-))

Comment: Commenting _classicthesis_ made the glossary work. Thank you @ChristianHupfer! 

I liked it a lot, anyway... Hints?

Comment: Not yet. There's the `numbers=enddot` option to the report class, which is not known -- this is used by `scrreprt.cls` actually. I'll try to figure out why `classicthesis` breaks this

Comment: `numbers=enddot` is a leftover from when I was playing with KOMA. Any help I can give you? Is there some "debug" mode?

Comment: You need to put `\setacronymstyle` before `\loadglsentries`. (The style has to be set before the entries are defined.)

Answer (score 1):

I found the workaround.

In order to use *glossaries* with ClassicThesis, you have to define the options:

```
style=long,nolist
```

So the minimum working options are:

```
\usepackage[style=long,nolist]{glossaries}
```

Thanks to Lorenzo Pantieri, "[Introduzione allo stile ClassicThesis](http://www.lorenzopantieri.net/LaTeX_files/ClassicThesis.pdf)" (trans. "Introduction to the ClassicThesis style", document in Italian).

I found it also referenced [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156308/classicthesis-conflicts-with-glossaries).

Thank you everybody for the interest, and @NicolaTalbot for this awesome package!