# Using glossaries with classicthesis template

Tags: pdftex, glossaries, acronyms, classicthesis

I want to start writing a report with the `classicthesis` template, since I like the layout. The problem is it uses the `acronyms` package, and I would prefer to use `glossaries`.

I have tried to insert my code from an older report I wrote, but this doesn't seem to work with `classicthesis`.

```
\usepackage[automake, nonumberlist, acronyms, nopostdot]{glossaries}
\newacronym{gpcr}{GPCR}{G protein-coupled receptor}
\makeglossary

\cleardoublepage\section*{Abbreviations}
Acronym test: \glspl{gpcr}. 2nd test: \gls{gpcr}.
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title=]
```

The lookup  works as expected, but absolutely nothing is printed in the glossaries section.

As this was working in my previous report, I am wondering if something from `classicthesis` is somehow overriding the `\printglossary` command.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The correct usage of `glossaries` requires `\makeglossaries` in the preamble, not `\makeglossary` and the usage of the `makeglossaries` script. In my opinion, `classicthesis` should not be used, however

Comment: @ChristianHupfer – Thanks for the reply. Why do you say `classicthesis` shouldn't be used? I really like the result. Do you have another, similar suggestion for a template?

I tried `\makeglossaries` this doesn't seem to change anything. And as I said I copied everything from an old report, and it's still working there. I've also tried `\makenoidxglossaries` and `\printnoidxglossaries`, and still no output. Is it possible this is a clash with a setting from `classicthesis`?

Comment: @anothersimonharris: Most likely just because that 'template' does weird things. It uses `titlesec` and `fancyhdr` together, if I remember correctly, and that's weird. It's typographical design is doubtful.

Comment: This https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/wiki/glossaries helps?

Comment: Or this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156308/classicthesis-conflicts-with-glossaries?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - I'm starting to think you're right. I've tried a lot of things now, with no luck. Time to look for another template...

Comment: @PhilipPirrip – Thanks, but unfortunately not! I had already seen these posts

Comment: Are you saying not even the example in the answer on my second link works? Everything up to date? Sometimes people work with a mix of old and new packages and only reinstalling the whole TeX distribution helps, especially on Windows. I know of at least two people who wrote huge theses using glossaries and ct!

Comment: @PhilipPirrip No, I can't get it to work. But just compiling that short example alone I was able to spot a warning that I had missed before: `pdfTeX warning (dest): name{glo:gpcr} has been referenced but does not exist,
 replaced by a fixed one`.

As far as I'm aware, all packages are up to date. `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.1.30)` &
`Package: glossaries 2019/01/06 v4.42 (NLCT)`

Comment: The only difference I can find between my report where it is working is that compiling creates a file called `main.acn` which contains all the glossary entries. There is also a file called `main.glo`, but it's empty. For `classicthesis` there is no `.acn` file, however the entries are listed in `main.glo`.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip I've solved this once I realised how these files weren't being created properly. Apparently for compiling, I first have to run the indexing. It's been a while since I had to write a report in latex. Plus I think TexPad for mac might have been doing this automatically for me before, and I'm using TextMate now. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't running the `makeindex` command before compiling. Hence, the `.acn` file wasn't being created.

Comment: Actually you compile, then `makeindex` (or better: `makeglossaries`) and compile again. If you run makeindex before (first) compilation there is nothing that `makeindex` can work on ;-)